# Transcribe randomly outputs completely wrong URI

Tags: url, transcribe, path, site-url

I'm using Transcribe 1.6.1 and EE 2.8.1.

I'm getting a weird thing happening when using the `{exp:transcribe:uri}` tag to output different URLs.

In my footer I have the usual Sitemap | Terms | Disclaimer| Privacy | Contact links, but only Contact isn't working correctly. It outputs `M140o93H7pQ09L8X1t49cHY01Z5j4TT91fGfr` instead of `/en/contact`

I've done some debugging on this one and I've found that the rest of the links output in the format of `http://domain.tld/en/path` but contact is outputting `/contact/` only. I looked into it further and discovered that even though `site_url='yes'` is supposed to be default param for this function but when parsing contact it is set as no. So I've gotten around this issue by explicitly setting `site_url='yes'` in my code.

I'm happy to have fixed the problem but this one is really bugging me why it's being so weird. Anyone have any ideas on this one?

Also, couldn't find any way to contact the developer on this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the long random string is the result of a run time pseudo caching that the template system in ExpressionEngine uses.  (If you google that string M40o93H7pQ09L8X1t49cHY01Z5j4TT91fGfr you will find loads of live EE sites where this issue is present).  That being said, the fix is very easy!  This happens when the same tag is present on a given page multiple times.  Usually one is inside a tag pair and the other isn't (so the pseudo caching doesn't get cleaned up).  If you go to the tag where this is present and just add something like work="yes" (really just making it so the tag string is seen differentially by the template parser)  it should do the trick. (please note, this should only be done on tags that display on the front end as that random string.)

Comment: Yeah that makes sense, I have a link to the contact page on there 3/4 times. It also must be why it was coming out without the site URL because it was caching the ones above which didn't include the site URL. Super easy fix - Thanks for that!

Edit: Would it be worth putting into the docs?